# Writing to multiple files with Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm scraping a website with Scrapy and would like to split the results into two parts. Usually I call Scrapy like this:

```
$ scrapy crawl articles -o articles.json
$ scrapy crawl authors  -o  authors.json
```

The two spiders are completely independent and don't communicate at all. This setup works for smaller websites, but larger websites have just too many authors for me to crawl like this.

How would I have the `articles` spider tell the `authors` spider what pages to crawl and maintain this two-file structure? Ideally, I'd rather not write the author URLs to a file and then read it back with the other spider.

Comment: I think the problem will be the size of the files. This solution won't scale very well (as I am sure you already noticed). have you though about a database or -store for this? Some schema-less solution would come to my mind for this. I don't think you will be happy with just 2 huge files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using command line arguments for the author scraper:

```
class AuthorSpider(BaseSpider):
    ...

    def __init__(self, articles):
        self.start_urls = []

        for line in articles:
            article = json.loads(line)
            self.start_urls.append(data['author_url'])
```

Then, I added the duplicates pipeline outlined in the [Scrapy documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#duplicates-filter):

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

class DuplicatesPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ids_seen = set()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if item['id'] in self.ids_seen:
            raise DropItem("Duplicate item found: %s" % item)
        else:
            self.ids_seen.add(item['id'])
            return item
```

Finally, I passed the article JSON lines file into the command:

```
$ scrapy crawl authors -o authors.json -a articles=articles.json
```

It's not a great solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

all depends on your business logic , but here is my suggestion

i am supposing each article should have an author/authors.

so why you are crawling same page multiple times for getting articles & authors ?

so i think your crawler should only crawl articles that should contains authors as well so extract articl and author at the same time with one scraper and Use Scrapy [pipeline](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) to write multiple json files that can separate article and authors.

one more point is for very big data json is not recommended use [jsonlines](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html)